# Why does PhpStorm allow for null return type on function using yield?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I used PhpStorm to auto add the return type in the function below:

```
/**
 * @return \Generator|null
 */
function yieldTest(): ?\Generator
{
    yield from [1, 2, 3];
}
```

My question: Why does it add the `null` option alongside `\Generator`?

I can't see a way for this to return null so I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something in the way `yield` works or if this is a quirk from PhpStorm's side and can safely be ditched?

**Update:**

To clarify - I am asking why PHPStorm generated the return type as `?\Generator`.

I understand that it then added `null` to the php doc `@return` tag because on the `?`.

**Update 2:**

Here is the full code form a test file before generating extra bits:

```
class yieldTestClass
{
    public function yieldTest()
    {
        yield from [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

And here is the code after choosing "Declare the return type" from the context menu on the method name:

```
class yieldTestClass
{
    public function yieldTest(): ?\Generator
    {
        yield from [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a native feature in the IDE or from a plugin but if it is a plugin I am guessing it would be this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-

Same question either way though.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen if you call it directly it just keeps returning the full `\Generator` instance. If you stick it into a foreach or whatever after having gone over the result set beforehand it just auto rewinds. So overall I've not managed to get it to return null in any way I can think of.

Comment: Please provide a code BEFORE types were generated so anybody can try it in local environment. Maybe it's not PhpStorm that does it (but some other plugin, not bundled one). For that the initial code sample is needed (so we all checking the same). Ideally whole file content (in case if it depends on some other stuff).

Comment: Good shout, added before and after for total clarity @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inspection and intended fix (the code added) is provided by a **Php Inspections (EA Extended) plugin**.

Please report to a plugin author: https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues

Comment: Ok so just to be clear - this is a bug in the plugin and there is indeed no way for `yield` to actually come up with `null` here?

Comment: I'm not using generators much, so cannot give you a 100% answer. Even if you do `yield ;` or something like `yield from null;`, it still will be a Generator instance.

Comment: Just noticed that if you generate the PHP doc `@return` tag with PHPStorm *before* generating the return type with the plugin, you actually get `@return \Generator` without the option for `null` so in light of that and everything else I think we're looking a t a bug in the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` means "the return type declaration is not mandatory and can theroetically be omitted". PHPStorm does not do dynamic analysis if you really return null or not.

> As of PHP 7.1.0, return values can be marked as nullable by prefixing
>   the type name with a question mark (**?**). This signifies that the
>   function returns either the specified type or NULL.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Consider the code examples:

```
    /**
     * @return Generator|null
     */
    function yieldTest(): ?\Generator
    {
        yield from [1, 2, 3];
    }
```

---

```
    /**
     * @return Generator
     */
    function yieldTest(): \Generator
    {
        yield from [1, 2, 3];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get that the php doc type hint includes `null` because of the `?`. Thing is that it was PHPStorm that generated this bit `: ?\Generator`, so *it* added the `?` and that's the part I am wondering about. I'll update my question in case that wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: @Bananaapple your question was better as it was before, now it's like you are asking why php storm has this setting by default, which makes it off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's not about programing but how you use a tool (which would be asked on Superuser SE).

Comment: I suppose a better question would have been what the correct return type of a method using yield should be and if it could ever be null - thus eliminating the uncertain IDE element of the question.